# Show all numeric rows or vice-versa postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named "temp_table" and a column named "temp_column" of type varchar. The problem is "temp_column" must be of type integer. If I will just automatically update the table into type integer, it will generate an error since some data has non-numeric data in it.

I want a query that will show all rows if "temp_column" has non-numeric values in it (or the other way around) and update or SET the value accordingly. I'm having a hard time since ISNUMERIC is not available in postgresql.

how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

This will show all rows where you have non-integer values in that column. It uses a regular expression to find all values that have anything else than just numbers in it:

```
select * 
from temp_table
where temp_column ~ '[^0-9]';
```

this can also be used in an update statement:

```
update temp_table
   set temp_column = null
where temp_column ~ '[^0-9]';
```

This will also filter out "numeric" values like `3.14` as those aren't integers.

Comment: The 'vice-versa' query to get rows where the temp_column is numeric select * 
from temp_table
where temp_column !~ '[^0-9]';

Comment: @TomGerken: `where temp_column ~ '[0-9]+'`  would also do it